# Unsigned na chave primária aumenta minhas possibilidades?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

Estava montando um banco pra um projeto pessoal e me deparei criando uma tabela pra guardar alguns poucos valores, nesta iria usar um `TINYINT` como chave primária, já que presumo que não irei passar de 100 registros, mas se acontecer quero ter um teto maior que 127.
(o exemplo acima é hipotético, servindo apenas pra explicar a pergunta. Já estou usando `INT(2)`).

Então gostaria de saber, considerando que os valores da chave começam em **0**, usar o `UNSIGNED` na chave primária me permite cadastrar mais valores? Já que os valores negativos passam a ser utilizados nos positivos?

(Certo que posso cadastrar utilizar chaves negativas e seria útil manter sem o `UNSIGNED` nesse caso, mas não é algo que utilizarei).

É comum/preciso utilizar sempre?

Comment: Revendo 4 anos depois, esse é um exemplo de porque o accept não deveria definir ordenação de respostas, justamente pelo fato de que é comum resposta [errada](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fKps.png) ficar acima das corretas, como aconteceu aqui - e pior, com votos positivos - afinal, o accept é dado por quem justamente está com dúvida. Para quem não entendeu, por ex. de -10 a 10 tem a mesma quantidade de possibilidades que de 0 a 20. O _unsigned_ não muda isso. Ele facilita autonumeração, mas nada impede de [fazer insert usando os negativos](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b92e5/1) usando todo o range.

Comment: @Bacco acabei de ver essa resposta, até concordo, mas precisa ver o historico também, a primeria resposta do Maniero não era boa, a pergunta não foi pensada na compactação, mas sim no autoincrement mesmo, como o comentário do Murilo na resposta do próprio Maniero, mas a parte da compactação está realmente incorreta e estou mudando o aceite

Comment: Note que não é uma critica ao "aceite" em si, mas ao sistema de ordenação, que foi corrigido recentemente (agora o aceite não ordena mais por padrão). Defendo a liberdade de vc dar o aceite no que quiser, só acho que o sistema tinha um defeito grave que era uma pessoa só mudar a ordem por mais absurdo que o post fosse, minando a avaliação coletiva. Como o V verdinho fazia a resposta aceita ficar no topo, ela ganhava muito up sem a devida análise. Agora o _default_ é só voto mexer na ordenação.

Comment: Outra coisa é que meu comment ficou obsoleto depois que corrigiram, e não removi. Reforçando, foi uma critica ao sistema e a votos positivos sem análise, da comunidade, deixando um alerta visível para visitantes futuros que algo tinha erro na aceita. De forma alguma não teve intenção de criticar sua pessoa especificamente,  nem à liberdade de vc aceitar o que gostar mais. Com o sistema como está hoje, melhorou muito. Depois vou remover meus comments, deixo aqui só pra dar tempo de vc ler depois.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se usar o `UNSIGNED`, o `ID` vai de zero a 255. Se não usar, vai de -128 a 127.

Então **não aumenta** suas possibilidades, você continuará tendo 256 valores possíveis. A diferença é que com `UNSIGNED` só pode usar todos positivos. Não há compactação alguma, muda a representação, mas não o dado ou tamanho.

Em geral as pessoas só usam **um** banco de dados apenas. E quando usa outros, ou a pessoa deixa ruim para todos, ou acaba fazendo adaptações para cada um.

Eu prefiro não usar porque pode dar impedância com a linguagem. Se acha que vai usar mais que 127, use `SMALLINT`. Gastar um byte a mais em 200 registros normalmente não vai fazer a mínima diferença em qualquer dispositivo que use o MySQL e você afasta a preocupação de vez, em vez de fazer micro-otimização e continuar trabalhando muito na margem.

Cuidado porque há ferramentas que colocam o `UNSIGNED` por conta própria.

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ah sim, tinha visto, mas acho que expressei um pouco mal na pergunta sem o título anterior, é realmente necessário? removendo o valor negativo posso perder algo?

Comment: É necessário, senão vai até o 127, a não ser que use negativos, o que é estranho para `ID`, se você precisa ou não de tudo isto é outra estória.

Comment: @bigown Para casos reais e práticos, aumenta sim, pois somente números positivos são usados. Sobre o terceiro parágrafo, melhor nem comentar.

Comment: Eu aprendi matemática de outra forma, no que eu aprendi uma faixa que vai de -128 até 127, dá 256 possibilidades, a faixa de 0 até 255 dá 256 possibilidades. 256 é igual a 256, então não consigo ver aumento.

Answer (score 2):

Características de uma chave primária:

1. Seu valor sempre deve ser único. Se você utiliza uma chave primária composta, a combinação dos campos deve ser única
2. A coluna destinada a chave primária não poderá conter valores nulos, portanto, seu campo deve ser declarado como `NOT NULL`

Tendo isso em mente, adotou-se o uso do `INT` para chaves primárias pois este tem o tempo de leitura bem baixo em relação a outros tipos (caractere, ponto flutuante...)

Por questões de tamanho do banco (quando você trabalha em espaços limitados de armazenamento) você pode poupar alguns bytes utilizando modificadores: `TINYINT`, `SMALLINT`, etc... Assim como caso necessário, pode-se fazer uso do `BIGINT` para tabelas com grandes quantidades de dados.

Também é uma boa prática o uso do modificador `AUTO_INCREMENT`, que garante a cada novo registro o autoincremento da chave.

Finalmente, respondendo sua pergunta, o modificador `UNSIGNED` garante apenas valores positivos para a chave, que usualmente é composta por inteiros. Entretanto, em via de regra, uma chave é definida por um elemento único, não importando o seu valor numérico.

Answer (score 1):

Aumenta sim!

Ademais, considero importante analisar se realmente é necessário este nível de compactação para a coluna.

Você está trabalhando com dispositivos limitados, com pouco espaço em disco, onde isto representa uma diferença significativa? Eventualmente um tipo muito específico pode não se suportado por outro banco de dados, engessando sua aplicação.

Comment: Boa resposta, tinha mudado o titulo acabou mudando um pouco o que esperava da pergunta (vou editar novamente), mas era bem isso que estava querendo entender. Hm, sabe me dizer se é comum utilizarem o `UNSIGNED` ou a maioria deixa sem pra manter essa questão de suporte?

Comment: Acredito que não é comum! Sugiro ainda utilizar um tipo padrão e grande o suficiente para qualquer entidade da sua aplicação, facilitando a manutenção e evolução da mesma.

Comment: Na verdade não aumenta as possibilidades. O que facilita é a autonumeração, só isso (de certa forma, o autor já pos a resposta na própria pergunta se for ver).